# Avalonia UI Multiple Selection Modes for ListBox Programmatically

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm creating my own user control for an application in AvaloniaUI. I want to set default values for the `SelectionMode`, `ItemsPanelTemplate`, `ListBoxItem Styles`, and `DataTemplate`.

```
using Avalonia.Controls;

namespace WFClient.Controls;

public class DirectoryListBox : ListBox
{
    public DirectoryListBox()
    {
        // SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple & SelectionMode.Toggle;
        // ItemsPanel = new WrapPanel();
        // ListBoxItemStyle = something;
        // DataTemplates.Add( /* something */ );
    }
}
```

This is what I want to mimic, in XAML:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple,Toggle">
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

      <ListBox.Styles>
        <Style Selector="ListBoxItem">
          <Setter Property="Width" Value="125"/>
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
      </ListBox.Styles>

      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Border BoxShadow="0 0 2 2 LightGray" Margin="3">
            <!-- stuff -->
          </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Two questions:

1. Is it best to make this control programmatically? If so, how?
2. Can I define this control in XAML instead, somewhere in my application resources? If so, how?

Comment: I think the easiest way to achieve that is to create new `UserControl` and put the `ListBox` in it's xaml code where you can set all the default values. Then you can create styled properties in your user control that you want to be modifiable and bind them to the list box properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1, like @radoslawik suggested, is to just create the UserControl and expose what you need as styled properties. However, as simple as it sounds, its also obscuring the `ListBox` and forces you to make property shims.

Option 2, which I would suggest is to create an axaml control inheriting from `ListBox`. The trick is that the control itself is defined in axaml and in the code behind (xaml.cs). Instead of using `UserControl` tag in the xaml you use `local:MyControlName` tag. For example, this would be the UserControlList.axaml:

```xml
<local:UserControlList xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test01"
                 x:Class="Test01.UserControlList"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple,Toggle">

    <local:UserControlList.Styles>
        <Style Selector="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="125"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </local:UserControlList.Styles>

    <local:UserControlList.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </local:UserControlList.ItemsPanel>

    <local:UserControlList.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="sys:String">
            <Border BoxShadow="0 0 2 2 LightGray" Margin="3">
                <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:UserControlList.ItemTemplate>

</local:UserControlList>
```

Notice that this is no longer a container control. You are working within the context of the class inherited from ListBox. So you cannot (or should not) go and create a new control template, but you can do a lot of adjustments to the inherited control itself. In the example, we set the SelectionMode, defined child styles and proveded `ItemPanel` and `ItemTemplate` (to make demo functional I added a simple label to your data template). In the backend code, you inherit the `ListBox` AND you override `StyleKeyOverride` :

```cs
using System;
using Avalonia.Controls;

namespace Test01;

public partial class UserControlList : ListBox
{
    public UserControlList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override Type StyleKeyOverride => typeof(ListBox);
}
```

This override is important so that Avalonia would apply default (fluent, etc) style to your control as if it was a `ListBox` itself. Without this, style selectors would not trigger for your control, and/or you would have to create styles for it yourself.

To use your control, just inject it where needed and treat it as you would a ListBox. In the demo I created a 3 item string list in resources and bound it to ItemsSource. But, you are not limited to that, since we did not obscure `ListBox` but extended it you can directly access any public property from `ListBox`, including applying additional styles, etc, etc.

MainWindow.axaml:

```xml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=System.Runtime"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test01"
        x:Class="Test01.MainWindow"
        Title="Test01">
    <Window.Resources>
        <scg:ArrayList x:Key="Items">
            <sys:String>Hello</sys:String>
            <sys:String>World</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Again</sys:String>
        </scg:ArrayList> 
    </Window.Resources>
    <!-- user control list -->
    <local:UserControlList ItemsSource="{StaticResource Items}"/>
</Window>
```